# MySQL debian-sys-maint quit and connect

Tags: mysql, logging

Hi all I have recently noticed that in my mysql.log file that it is getting flooded with the below messages.

I am not sure why the debian-sys-maint keeps making this connection and then quitting, it has all the right credentials so it is not a permissions issue to my understanding.

Does anyone have any ideas thank you

```
150903 12:12:17   192 Connect   debian-sys-maint@localhost on
                  192 Quit
150903 12:12:18   193 Connect   debian-sys-maint@localhost on
                  193 Quit
150903 12:12:19   194 Connect   debian-sys-maint@localhost on
                  194 Quit
```

Comment: Did you change your logrotate b4?

Comment: I understand that that is only for slow queries and errors this issue seems more general

Comment: *this issue seems to be for general_log

Answer (score 0):

The log is correct.
Connection to MySql will quit after connecting and executing a query.

You might keep the connection alive, but in case you are executing into something that starts & terminates with a single HTTP request/response (like a PHP script), then it's normal that the connection to MySql gets closed at the end of the script.

Seeing that log just means that `global general_log` is active (instruction `SET global general_log = on;` executed in the MySql console).
If you don't want those logs just set `general_log` to `off`.

Otherwise, I would wonder more why there is no SQL query logged in between the *Connect* and the *Quit*.